# Change theme based on user role

Tags: 10

I have a scenario where I want to change my website theme based on user's role. Administrator users would have the Claro Claro, while content editors would have a custom theme or a downloaded theme.

I came across the [Role theme switcher](https://www.drupal.org/project/role_theme_switcher) and the [Role base theme switcher](https://www.drupal.org/project/role_based_theme_switcher) modules. The Role theme switcher module would work as the rows for each role are draggable.

> [image: screenshot]

Is there a way I can do this programmatically?